# If Statement ( Unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Can't find the problem. Whenever I only input 1,an error occur. It says that ( unexpected at this time.But whenever I input other numbers as long as it has a 2 decimal places, it's okay.

```
@echo off
cls
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo|set /p= Input: 
    set /p input=
    call :process
    endlocal
    goto :EOF

:process
if %input%==0 (
    echo Input is 0
    goto :EOF
)

if %input:~-3,1%==. (
    if %input:~0,-3%==0 (
        echo Less than 1
    ) else (
        echo Greater than 1
    )
) else (
    echo Equal to 1
)
goto :EOF
```

Comment: remove the `@echo off` and watch the output - you will clearly see, what is the problem.

Comment: I see. thanks~
An error appears because the parameters are not complete.

Comment: yes. To avoid this syntax-problem, put both sides of the equal sign to doublequotes: `if "%input%"=="0" (`. This will not solve any logical failures, but it keeps the batch from crashing with syntax error because if %input% is empty, the line is translated to `if ""=="0" (` instead of `if ==0 (`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if %input:~-3,1%==. (`

means if [the string from the FOURTH character of `input` for 1 character]==. (

When input is "1", [the string from the FOURTH character of `input` for 1 character] is empty, so this is interpreted as

`if ==. (`

The `if` statement expects `if string1 operator string2 (dothis)`

si it sees `==.` as string1 and can't work out what `(` means as an operator - it is expecting one of a limited set; so it complains that `(` was not expected.

Cure:

```
if "%input:~-3,1%"=="." (
```